# Generate table from MySQL to PDF (using PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf, mpdf

I'm trying to export the table (filtered) from MySQL to pdf.

The main problem here is that it only prints the last result on the list, instead of printing all the results.

I have  tried other code but I still get the same result. I don't know what is wrong with my code:

```
<?php
include("configsample.php");
?>
<?php

$string=$_GET['string'];
$course=$_GET['course'];
$category=$_GET['category'];
$from=$_GET['from'];
$to=$_GET['to'];

if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
$search_string = " AND restu_title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%'";
}
if ($_REQUEST["course"]<>'') {
$search_course = " AND restu_course='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["course"])."'";
}
if ($_REQUEST["category"]<>'') {
$search_category = " AND category='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["category"])."'";
}


if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year BETWEEN '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_course;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_course;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_course;
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_id>0".$search_string.$search_course.$search_category;
}
$html='<table>
<tr style="color:#010101; font:bold 13px Times New Roman; height:40px;">
<th>Research Title</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Proponent(s)</th>
<th>Adviser</th>
<th>Research Panel</th>
</tr>';
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
$html2='<tr>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_title'].'</td>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_year'].'</td>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_by'].'</td>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_ad'].'</td>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_panel'].'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
}
}

include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','Letter','','',20,20,18,16,9,9,'L');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->AddPage('L');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html2);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You overwrite $html2 in your whileloop. As long as there is another record, it will be fetched and html2 will always contain the value uf the last record.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) your text string to avoid `$html2` to be overwritten by the next value.

Everytime the loop is running, `$html2` is overwritten with the new value. In your case, you need to add a dot just before the equal symbol:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
    $html .='<tr>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_title'].'</td>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_year'].'</td>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_by'].'</td>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_ad'].'</td>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_panel'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Be careful to correctly place the `</table>`. If your SQL request has no result, the table will not be closed, rendering the HTML invalid.

You need to do it like this:

```
$html='<table>
    <tr style="color:#010101; font:bold 13px Times New Roman; height:40px;">
    <th>Research Title</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Proponent(s)</th>
    <th>Adviser</th>
    <th>Research Panel</th>
    </tr>';
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
        $html .='<tr>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_title'].'</td>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_year'].'</td>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_by'].'</td>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_ad'].'</td>
            <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_panel'].'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
}
$html .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried replacing the code but it gives me this error: "mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file:

Comment: This message occurs when you have var_dump or any error before $mpdf->. Try to var_dump($html) without making the pdf to see if there is no error, about de sql request.

Answer (score 0):

append $html2. You are assigning value in loop so it displaying only last record.

Use like this..

```
 $html2=$html2.'<tr>
    <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_title'].'</td>
    <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_year'].'</td>
    <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_by'].'</td>
    <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_ad'].'</td>
    <td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_panel'].'</td>
    </tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried replacing the code but it gives me this error: "mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file: